# How can I debug a pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

If while running a simple group by script in pig for large terabytes of data, the script got stuck at say 70%, then what can be done to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 13):

There are several method to debug a pig script. Simple method is step by step execution of a relation and then verify the result. These commands are useful to debug a pig script.

**DUMP** - Use the DUMP operator to run (execute) Pig Latin statements and display the results to your screen.

**ILLUSTRATE** - Use the ILLUSTRATE operator to review how data is transformed through a sequence of Pig Latin statements. ILLUSTRATE allows you to test your programs on small datasets and get faster turnaround times.

**EXPLAIN** - Use the EXPLAIN operator to review the logical, physical, and map reduce execution plans that are used to compute the specified relationship.

**DESCRIBE** - Use the DESCRIBE operator to view the schema of a relation. You can view outer relations as well as relations defined in a nested FOREACH statement.

More detail about these commands are available on this [link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/test.html).
Also please refer [developing and testing a pig script.](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch07.html) to know more detail.

If you want to debug whole script during execution then you need to write below code at top of your script

```
-- set the debug mode on 
SET debug 'on'
-- set a job name of your job.
SET job.name 'my job'
```

This will allow to run your script into debug mode. mode detail on about `SET` command is available on this [link](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cmds.html#set)

Answer (score 1):

When you say the script is stuck at 70%, I assume you mean the MR job is 70% complete.

It's best to look at MR and YARN logs (and if needed, HDFS logs) at that point for more information about what MR/YARN is doing. Logs can be typically found under */var/log/hadoop-mapreduce* and */var/log/hadoop-hdfs* in Cloudera Manager managed clusters. You may need to examine logs from multiple nodes in the cluster where YARN NodeManagers are running.

In case your script is stuck with a Pig issue (i.e. issue in Pig code, not MR/HDFS code), it is useful to increase the log4j logging level in Pig:
**pig -d DEBUG** is the command line option to set the logging level to DEBUG for example.